# Java BufferedWriter issue

Tags: java

I've encountered this weird thing which prevents me from creating a new line in a `.txt` file, using a `BufferedWriter` connected to a `FileWriter`. However, if I save the file as the default option, `.file`. The spaces would be included in the document. The referred part of the code below:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
for(Account acc : list) {
    writer.write(acc.getFirst() + "," + acc.getLast() + "," + acc.getPassword() + "," + acc.getEmail() + "\n");
}
```

The values in the `.write`. method are all Strings.

Comment: What do you mean by this: " However, if I save the file as the default option, .file. The spaces would be included in the document."? Your question is unclear. (I don't see what this has to do with Swing at all...)

Comment: The argument "file" in the FileWriter object is the return value of a `JFileChooser`. That's why I included it as well. But on second though, tagging it as "Swing" was unnecessary.
What I mean by that, I have the option to choose the file's extension. The default extension is .file. However, I'd like to save it as a .txt file.

Comment: Basically, if the list consists of more than 2 Account objects. And is saved as a .txt document. The "\n" instruction is skipped. On the other hand, if the .file extension is chosen, the "\n" instruction is not skipped.

Comment: You are probably using windows and opening the file in notepad, which does not understand `\n` as a terminator, and expects `\r\n` instead. Your problem has nothing to do with Java - open the .txt files in another editor.

Comment: What makes you think it's skipped? How are you validating that? Are you opening it Notepad on Windows by any chance? If so, the problem is that the line break on Windows is `\r\n`, not just `\n`... It would be very helpful if you'd convert your question to show a short but *complete* example (I suspect you can do that just with hard-coded values really easily... no need for an Account class) - and unless it's actually got anything to do with Swing, I suggest you remove all references to Swing from the question.

Comment: Changed it to `\r\n` and it worked perfectly for file extensions.

Comment: Swing has precisely nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @Steven1903 use System.lineSeperator(), more compat for multiple OS's (\r\n will do fine however)

Comment: Hard coding `\r\n` is not the right approach. You will find extra characters when the program executed on a *nix system. Use `line.separator` property instead.